# OpenGL: Problem With Phong Model Specular Lighting

Tags: c++, opengl, light, phong

I know that specular lighting is also based on the view direction. But I can't find what the default view direction is in old OpenGL function glLight(.. GL_SPECULAR..). How does it determine the direction of the view?

Answer (score 0):

In old OpenGL lighting is done in view space, where camera coordinates are (0, 0, 0), so view direction vector is equal to fragment's position.